# JSON with Python "object must be str, not dict"

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to interpret data from the Twitch API with Python. This is my code:

```
from twitch.api import v3
import json

streams = v3.streams.all(limit=1)
list = json.loads(streams) 
print(list)
```

Then, when running, I get:

> TypeError, "the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'"

Any ideas? Also, is this a method in which I would actually want to use data from an API?

Comment: Try printing `streams`. It is likely that it has already been JSON parsed.

Comment: Aside: one ought not use `list` (or the name of any other built-in function) as a variable name. Subsequent code cannot invoke `list()` anymore and expect the standard result.

Comment: @DanD. Ah yes, so printing streams does work.  Now, how would I take parts of this data and use it?

Comment: @Karrigan: Like literally any other `dict`. Look up keys in it, iterate it to get keys, call `.items()` on it to get key/value pairs, whatever.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Excellent, thank you.  Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: you can pretty print the dict by `import pprint` and then `print(pprint.pprint(streams))` to get a feel for what's in it.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html) `json.loads()` will parse a string into a json hierarchy (which is often a `dict`). Therefore, if you don't pass a string to it, it will fail.

> json.loads(s, encoding=None, cls=None, object_hook=None,
>   parse_float=None, parse_int=None, parse_constant=None,
>   object_pairs_hook=None, **kw) Deserialize s (a str instance containing
>   a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.
>
> The other arguments have the same meaning as in load(), except
>   encoding which is ignored and deprecated.
>
> If the data being deserialized is not a valid JSON document, a
>   JSONDecodeError will be raised.

From the [Twitch API](https://github.com/ingwinlu/python-twitch/blob/master/twitch/api/v3/streams.py) we see that the object being returned by `all()` is a `V3Query`. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/ingwinlu/python-twitch/blob/master/twitch/queries.py) and [documentation](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/streams.md#get-streams) for that, we see it is meant to return a list. Thus, you should treat that as a list rather than a string that needs to be decoded.

Specifically, the `V3Query` is a subclass of `ApiQuery`, in turn a subclass of `JsonQuery`. That class explicitly runs the query and passes a function over the results, [`get_json`](https://github.com/ingwinlu/python-twitch/blob/master/twitch/scraper.py). That source explicitly calls `json.loads()`... so you don't need to! Remember: never be afraid to dig through the source.

Comment: That's just saying it failed because it failed. In fact, the api is already doing the decode so you don't have to do it again.

Comment: No, that's saying it failed because the type being passed to the function is incorrect. Which is the cause of the cited error.

Comment: OP's problem is that he didn't realize that the JSON had already been decoded to python.

Comment: I think you're splitting hairs, but in terms of understanding why he got the TypeError it's important to determine what might throw it, understand what it expects and what it will return. We confirm that the input is bad by understanding that `loads` expects a string, and thinks it's getting a dict.

Comment: You say splitting hairs but then you changed your answer to include a description of what went wrong. That's what I meant.

Comment: Well, I was still digging through the Twitch code. The code failure was a misinterpretation of the api output. The OP's reasoning failure (and why they didn't figure this out themselves) was that they didn't know how to interpret or diagnose the TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

after streams = v3.streams.all(limit=1)
try using 
streams = json.dumps(streams)

As the streams should be a JSON string and be in the form:
'{"key":value}' 
instead of just dict form:
{"key":value}